# javascript variable value not updating with new one after a html form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a 8 textbox in my html form wrapped with `div` ids `fa1` to `fa8`. two are visible by default and 6 are hidden. I am using a two buttons `addfa` and `removefa` to show and hide the divs.I need to keep the div count after form submit and I am using below html to update the `value` in html (by default it is 3 and if I display a hidden div it will change to 4..)

html code:

```
<div class="add_remove_column">
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['countfa'])){  
 $valueid = $_POST['countfa'];
 ?>
<input  type="hidden" id="countfa" name="countfa" value="<?= $valueid ?>" readonly>
<?php
 }else{
  ?>

<input  type="hidden" id="countfa" name="countfa" value="3" readonly> 
 <?php
 }
?>
    <button type="button" onClick="AddNewFa();" id="addfa" > + Add New FA </button>
    <button  type="button" onClick="RemoveNewFa();" id="removefa" disabled="disabled"> - Remove FA</button> 
</div>
```

javascript for add button:

```
function AddNewFa() 
    {
        var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),9) ;
        if( facount < 9)
            {
                facount = facount+1;

                for(i=3;i<9;i++)
                {
                    if( i<facount )
                        $('#fa'+i).slideDown("fast");
                    else
                        $('#fa'+i).slideUp("fast"); 

                }
                $('#countfa').val(facount);  

            }
        if( facount ==9 )
            { $('#addfa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
        if( facount ==4 )
            { $('#removefa').removeAttr("disabled");}

    }
```

As per the javascript if the facount value is 4 and above it suppose to remove the `disabled` attribute from the `removefa` button.

I see if I select additional one div, the `countfa` changing to 4 after form submit, but the `removefa` button still disabled. It suppose to be in enabled state, what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `facount` just before the `if` loop gets executed? Is it having the expected value?

Comment: With the change that Arun has mentioned in his answer, the JS seems to be working fine. Maybe there is some other problem. Is your code hosted somewhere so that I can have a look at it?

Comment: I will setup a fiddle and will let you know..

Comment: @ Harry :      I am having issue to setup a fidle or this. I just added a javascript echo as innterhtml to see if the javascript getting variable value after form submit \ page refresh, but I see it is not. Only after I pressing the button the script is executing. I have added a `window.onload = function ()1 with Arun's code to see if the variable getting the valur..but not..

Comment: Should I move this discussion to a chat? I think seeing your full code would help. If not a fiddle, maybe you can just upload your file somewhere?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38685/discussion-between-acr-and-harry)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for greater than or equals to. Also need to use `.prop()` to set disabled property

```
if (facount >= 4) {
    $('#removefa').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

or try

```
$('#removefa').prop('disabled', facount < 4);
```

Comment: I tried both the method..but I still see it is in disabled state